# Maximal vs upper bound in a POSET

Tags: order-theory

I am studying the concept of a Partially Ordered Set, abbreviated as POSET and one author says that a

> "a maximal element need not be an upper bound."

I tried browsing the net to find an example of the preceding statement, but can't find a lucky one.

Can someone provide me an example of this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: You really should read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/why-should-we-accept-answers).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a more complete reference on the two terms, see the [Wikipedia page on Zorn's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma) and the links to the two terms from there.

For the specific terms, it helps to consider that *maximal element* and *non-dominated element* are used synonymously (the latter is much clearer to me). A maximal element $x$ is one such that there is no $y > x$ (no $y$ that dominates $x$). An upper bound of some set, on the other hand is some $x$ such that $x \ge y$ for all $y$. So, the maximal element need not be related to all elements, but an upper bound does.

In a partial ordering, an upper bound is a maximal element, but the reverse is not necessarily true (and finding a maximal element is often possible when finding an upper bound is not). In a total ordering, the two are equivalent.

Trivial example of the difference: let $\{x, y\}$ be a poset such that $x$ and $y$ are not related. $x$ is a maximal element (it is not the case that $y > x$) but not an upper bound (because we don't have $y \le x$ either).

Comment: @jun: Note, however, that *maximal element* is the usual term.

Comment: @William: I got confused of your statement that $\{x,y\}$ is a POSET such that $x$ and $y$ are not related. :D)

Comment: So, a poset is just a set of elements, and some relation, $\prec$ between them with some properties (transitive, reflexive, antisymmetric). Let these elements be $x$ and $y$. Let $x \prec x$ and $y \prec y$ (this is needed for the reflexive part). Importantly, $x \not \prec y$ and $y \not \prec x$. It should be easy to check antisymmetry and transitivity. Finally, observe that there is no $z \neq x$ such that $x \prec z$. Therefor, $x$ is maximal. However, $x$ is not an upper bound because we do not have $y \prec x$.

Comment: @William Macrae: Thanks for your help, I got it now.

Comment: It was my understanding that a maximal element must be in the set. So given a set $Q \subset P$ an element $x \in P$ can be an upper bound for $Q$ but not a maximal element.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be a set of at least two elements. Define a partial order $\prec$ on $X$ by,
$$
a\prec b\Leftrightarrow a=b,\text{ for all }a,b\in X.
$$
Let $A\subseteq X$ be a subset containing at least two elements. Clearly each element of $A$ is a maximal element of,  $A$ but $A$ does not have any upper bound. Hence, a maximal element need not be an upper bound.

Comment: I like it. So, the idea is if there exists an upper bound $u$ for $A$, then for every $x\in X$, it follows (by the definition of the partial order) that $x=u$. This implies that $X=\{u\}$, a contradiction since $X$ has at least two elements. Am I right?

Comment: for every $x\in A$...... This implies that $A$ is singleton which is a contradiction.

Comment: Ah ok, I stand corrected, it should be $A$. Many thanks. :D)